# IBM's Worklight xcode .framework file

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Lots of business people are interested in using **IBM's Worklight** in mobile projects. We do iOS projects with **Objective C** and have no interest in, for example, Phone Gap.

An IBM Business Partner Sales guy told me there was a **.framework** file I could **download** and import into my **iOS Objective C projects in xcode**. He sent a link (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/worklight/) which doesn't lead to a file download on my Mac. Not even a file download of a Worklight trial.

**A Google Search does not lead to a .framework file download:**
https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+objective+c+worklight+.framework+file+download&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=ios+objective+c+worklight+.framework+file+download&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official

Other similar searches also yield no results. It's a little to hard to get.

It wouldn't be the first time that a salesman said something that wasn't true. But the salesman had good reason to suppose I could download Worklight at the very least.

The IBM page for Worklight had the word "Download" on a button with the information grabbing form (name,phone,email,company,SS#,girlfriend/boyfriend,hair-color,weight,etc). But no download upon successful form completion.

There is also this page which describes how to use it in your mobile App: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_use_cocoapod_to_add_worklight_or_bluemix_ios_api?lang=en

The first step of which sends you to the link above: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/worklight

Do any Stackoverflow iOS Objective C developers use IBM Worklight? Can anyone suggest a solution or even work around? Is it really this hard to use IBM software?

OSX 10.9.4; Firefox 31.0; Safari 7.0.6;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight 6.2 does not provide a .framework file for iOS.
I'd be interested to know who told you this.

---

Since you are not interested in Hybrid development using Worklight (read: using Cordova as part of your application), you are likely referring to the native development offering from Worklight.

Either way, to get started you need Worklight Studio, which is a plug-in for Eclipse that will generate artifacts for you, required for your (native) iOS application ([you can also use a CLI for this purpose](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_wl_cli_features.html) ([download](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/cli.html))).

You can get Worklight Studio 6.2.0.0, after downloading Eclipse, by navigating in Eclipse to Help > Eclipse Marketplace > search for "worklight".

After you've installed Worklight Studio, you can now proceed to create a Native API project, which is basically a server component and additional artifacts that you need to copy into your Xcode project, required in order to enable your application to communicate with the Worklight Server, use Worklight features, APIs, etc.

*The above is currently not bundled in the form of a .framework file.*

Now would be a good time to stop, and review the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/).

Specifically:

- [Creating your first native iOS Worklight application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_hello)
- [Invoking adapter procedures from native iOS applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_server_dev)
- [Additional user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_native_apps_ios.html)
- [Using CLI to create, build, and manage Worklight project artifacts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_adv_client_dev)

---

Using either Worklight Studio or Worklight CLI, you should be able to get the [blog post by Carlos Santana](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_use_cocoapod_to_add_worklight_or_bluemix_ios_api?lang=en) to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your response appears to be excellent. Once I confirm everything by downloading/installing, I'll mark this as the answer. It turns out it was an IBM **Business Partner** Sales guy.

Comment: This worked. I'm used to eclipse and was able to install the plugin from the market place. IBM's site **is** confusing. Thanks for your help.